# Comment form json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments, json

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to have a native comment-form return json instead of redirecting?

Thanks!

- Steven

Comment: The quick answer is no, but there are options. Take a look at [this comprehensive answer](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1404/77) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 2):

With a custom extension, you could. Just use the [`insert_comment_end` hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/comment/index.html#insert-comment-end), then do something like this:

```
if(ee()->input->is_ajax_request())
{
    ee()->extensions->end_script = TRUE;
    $data['comment_id'] = $comment_id;
    $data['moderated'] = $comment_moderate;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```